# Add Change-Id to previous commit

Tags: git, gerrit

I have many commits. But my last commit have not Change-Id. An can not push to Gerrit.

How to add Change-Id to previous commit?

Comment: Gerrit provides a [`commit-msg` hook script](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/cmd-hook-commit-msg.html) that will automatically add change-ids to your commits.  If you don't have this installed in your local repository you should.

Comment: @larsks how to do it now? And how ti fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gerrit provides a [`commit-msg` hook script](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/cmd-hook-commit-msg.html) that will automatically add change-ids to your commits.

The documentation to which I linked provides instructions for installing it:

> To obtain the commit-msg script use scp, wget or curl to download it to your local system from your Gerrit server.
>
> You can use either of the below commands:
>
> ```
> $ scp -p -P 29418 <your username>@<your Gerrit review server>:hooks/commit-msg <local path to your git>/.git/hooks/
>
> $ curl -Lo <local path to your git>/.git/hooks/commit-msg <your Gerrit http URL>/tools/hooks/commit-msg
> ```

Once you've installed the `commit-msg` hook, you can use `git commit --amend` to update your commit message; when you save it, the hook will add the `Change-Id` to the message.

Comment: What about the specific commit. In other words not the latest commit.

Comment: I believe that if you use `git rebase` to edit the commit of your choice; it should get updated in the same fashion.

Comment: Yes! git rebase -i @larsks

Answer (score 3):

First of all you need to install the "commit-msg" hook which is responsible to automatically add Change-Ids to your commits. To install and learn more about the hook see the [commit-msg Hook](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/cmd-hook-commit-msg.html) item in the Gerrit documentation.

To change your last commit just execute:

```
git commit --amend
```

Alternatively you can add the Change-Id to your commit message manually. Just add to commit message footer a line like the following:

```
Change-Id: Ic8aaa0728a43936cd4c6e1ed590e01ba8f0fbf5b
```

Change some Change-Id numbers randomly keeping the "I" at the beginning.

Comment: Using git log i do not see change-id

Comment: I added more info to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use [git-review](https://docs.releng.linuxfoundation.org/en/latest/gerrit.html#configure-the-repository) to while working with gerrit changes. Its easier to modify and submit change to the repository.

```
pip install --user git-review
git review -s  # this step does the same thing as @larsks
git commit -s --amend # adds the change-id
```